# can't resolve all parameters for xxx -- jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jestjs, ts-jest

I have one test in jest but it is failing. It is showing the next

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LoginService: (?).
>
> ```
> at syntaxError (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/external/npm/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:170:49)
> at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/packages/compiler/src/identifiers.ts:69:99)
> at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/packages/compiler/src/identifiers.ts:66:95)
> at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableTypeMetadata (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/packages/compiler/src/identifiers.ts:69:99)
> at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/packages/compiler/src/identifiers.ts:69:99)
> at /Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/packages/compiler/src/identifiers.ts:69:99
> at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
> at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/packages/compiler/src/identifiers.ts:69:99)
> at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/packages/compiler/src/identifiers.ts:62:21)
> at JitCompiler._loadModules (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/packages/compiler/src/compile_metadata.ts:482:40)
> at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/packages/compiler/src/compile_metadata.ts:482:40)
> at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/packages/compiler/src/compile_metadata.ts:482:40)
> at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js:615:29)
> at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js:583:29)
> at TestBedViewEngine.compileComponents (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:3360:29)
> at Function.TestBedViewEngine.compileComponents (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:3167:27)
> at /Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/src/app/views/auth/login/login.component.spec.ts:44:8
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:457:160)
> at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:150:35)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:457:48)
> at Zone.run (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:183:37)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/zone-patch/index.js:51:54)
> at Object.asyncJestLifecycle (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:53:37)
> at /Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:45:12
> at new Promise (<anonymous>)
> at mapper (/Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:28:19)
> at /Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:75:41
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
> ```

I could identify as i can get the error. If i remove the parameters in the constructor, the test is success.

The test is

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {LoginComponent} from './login.component';
import {LoginService} from '../../../services/login.service';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {UtilitiesService} from '../../../services/utilities.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {of} from 'rxjs';
import {CommunicatorService} from '../../../services/communicator.service';
import {LoadingService} from '../../../services/loading.service';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach((() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientModule, FormsModule],
      declarations: [
        LoginComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        HttpClient,
        LoadingService,
        UtilitiesService,
        ToastrService,
        {
          provide: Router,
          useValue: {
            navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: CommunicatorService,
          useValue: {
            http_post() { return of({}); },
          },
        },
        LoginService,
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('Create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The component is

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginService} from '../../../services/login.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {UtilitiesService} from '../../../services/utilities.service';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router, private utilitiesService:UtilitiesService, private toastr: ToastrService) {}
  private _email = '';
  private _password = '';
  private _isChecked = false;
  private _disable=false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.checkIsSaveUser();
  }

  checkIsSaveUser() {
    const emailSaved = localStorage.getItem('USER_ACTIVE');
    if(emailSaved !== undefined && emailSaved !== 'null' && emailSaved !== ''){
       this._email = emailSaved;
       this._isChecked = true;
    }
  }
  checkInfo(){
    return !this.utilitiesService.validatorsFields(this._email) ||
      !this.utilitiesService.validatorsFields(this._password)|| !this.utilitiesService.validatorsEmail(this._email);
  }
  saveUser() {
    if(!this._isChecked)  {
      this._isChecked = true;
      localStorage.setItem('USER_ACTIVE', this._email);
    } else   {
      this._isChecked = false;
      localStorage.setItem('USER_ACTIVE', '');
    }
  }

  login(){
    this.loginService.user = this._email;
    this.loginService.password = this._password;
    if(this._isChecked)  {
      localStorage.setItem('USER_ACTIVE', this._email);
    }
    this.loginService.login().subscribe(result => {
      this.loginService.tokenSecret = result.data.token;
      this.loginService.rol = result.data.rol;
      this.router.navigate(['admin/tables']);
    }, error => {
      this.toastr.error(error.error.code +': ' +  error.error.message, 'Error', {
        timeOut: 7000,
      });
    })
  }


  get password(): string {
    return this._password;
  }

  set password(value: string) {
    this._password = value;
  }

  get isChecked(): boolean {
    return this._isChecked;
  }

  set isChecked(value: boolean) {
    this._isChecked = value;
  }

  get disable(): boolean {
    return this._disable;
  }

  set disable(value: boolean) {
    this._disable = value;
  }

  get email(): string {
    return this._email;
  }

  set email(value: string) {
    this._email = value;
  }
}
```

Now i run the test, it is showing

[image: error]

Now if i remove the parameters in the constructor, it is success

The test is

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {LoginComponent} from './login.component';
import {LoginService} from '../../../services/login.service';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {UtilitiesService} from '../../../services/utilities.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {of} from 'rxjs';
import {CommunicatorService} from '../../../services/communicator.service';
import {LoadingService} from '../../../services/loading.service';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach((() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientModule, FormsModule],
      declarations: [
        LoginComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        HttpClient,
        LoadingService,
        UtilitiesService,
        ToastrService,
        {
          provide: Router,
          useValue: {
            navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: CommunicatorService,
          useValue: {
            http_post() { return of({}); },
          },
        },
        LoginService,
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('Create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The component is

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  private _email = '';
  private _password = '';
  private _isChecked = false;
  private _disable=false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.checkIsSaveUser();
  }

  checkIsSaveUser() {
    const emailSaved = localStorage.getItem('USER_ACTIVE');
    if(emailSaved !== undefined && emailSaved !== 'null' && emailSaved !== ''){
       this._email = emailSaved;
       this._isChecked = true;
    }
  }
  checkInfo(){
    return true;
  }
  saveUser() {
    if(!this._isChecked)  {
      this._isChecked = true;
      localStorage.setItem('USER_ACTIVE', this._email);
    } else   {
      this._isChecked = false;
      localStorage.setItem('USER_ACTIVE', '');
    }
  }

  login(){
    if(this._isChecked)  {
      localStorage.setItem('USER_ACTIVE', this._email);
    }
  }


  get password(): string {
    return this._password;
  }

  set password(value: string) {
    this._password = value;
  }

  get isChecked(): boolean {
    return this._isChecked;
  }

  set isChecked(value: boolean) {
    this._isChecked = value;
  }

  get disable(): boolean {
    return this._disable;
  }

  set disable(value: boolean) {
    this._disable = value;
  }

  get email(): string {
    return this._email;
  }

  set email(value: string) {
    this._email = value;
  }
}
```

now i run the test, it is success

[image]

I only remove the parameters in the constructor.

The github link  is the next [test](https://github.com/wilson1234567891962/Andes---ProyectoWeb/blob/feature/HU002/src/app/views/auth/login/login.component.spec.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in my error:

The first, we need to fix the next files

tsconfig.spec.json
tsconfig.json

Before  the tsconfig.spec.json file

```
{
  "extends": "tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {

  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
  ]
}
```

Now the updated tsconfig.spec.json file

```
{
  "extends": "tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
  ]
}
```

Before  the tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Now the tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

I fixed the first error (Can't resolve all parameters for LoginService: ) but now i am getting the next

> NullInjectorError:
> StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ToastrService -> InjectionToken
> ToastConfig]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ToastrService ->
> InjectionToken ToastConfig]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken ToastConfig!

Then i added the next in the test

> ToastrModule.forRoot()

The test was

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {LoginComponent} from './login.component';
import {LoginService} from '../../../services/login.service';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {UtilitiesService} from '../../../services/utilities.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpHandler} from '@angular/common/http';
import {of} from 'rxjs';
import {CommunicatorService} from '../../../services/communicator.service';
import {LoadingService} from '../../../services/loading.service';
import {ToastrModule, ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientModule, FormsModule, ToastrModule.forRoot()],
      declarations: [
        LoginComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        HttpClient,
        LoadingService,
        UtilitiesService,
        ToastrService,
        {
          provide: Router,
          useValue: {
            navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: CommunicatorService,
          useValue: {
            http_post() { return of({}); },
          },
        },
        {
          provide: LoginService,
          useValue: {
            login() { return of({}); },
          },
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('Create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The result is

```
/Users/wilson.gonzalez/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.1/bin/node --require /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/helpers/jest-intellij/lib/jest-intellij-stdin-fix.js /Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --colors --reporters /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/helpers/jest-intellij/lib/jest-intellij-reporter.js --verbose --testNamePattern=^LoginComponent  --runTestsByPath /Users/wilson.gonzalez/Desktop/proyecto_andes/Andes---ProyectoWeb/src/app/views/auth/login/login.component.spec.ts
ts-jest[versions] (WARN) Version 25.1.0 of jest installed has not been tested with ts-jest. If you're experiencing issues, consider using a supported version (>=24.0.0 <25.0.0). Please do not report issues in ts-jest if you are using unsupported versions.
ts-jest[versions] (WARN) Version 4.1.5 of typescript installed has not been tested with ts-jest. If you're experiencing issues, consider using a supported version (>=2.7.0 <4.0.0). Please do not report issues in ts-jest if you are using unsupported versions.
--------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files                 |   29.71 |    13.46 |    17.3 |   24.84 |                   
 app/services             |   18.75 |     4.76 |    5.55 |   13.55 |                   
  communicator.service.ts |   19.04 |        0 |       0 |   15.38 | 10-96             
  loading.service.ts      |   57.14 |      100 |       0 |      40 | 8-16              
  login.service.ts        |   25.92 |        0 |       0 |      20 | 13-73             
  utilities.service.ts    |    9.61 |     8.33 |   22.22 |    6.12 | 16-108            
 app/views/auth/login     |   57.77 |       50 |   43.75 |   53.65 |                   
  login.component.html    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  login.component.ts      |   56.81 |       50 |   43.75 |    52.5 | 39-59,71,79-87,95 
 environments             |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  environment.dev.ts      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  environment.prod.ts     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for statements (85%) not met: 29.71%
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for lines (80%) not met: 24.84%
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for functions (75%) not met: 17.3%
```

[image]